# When i want to push github throw thi error

Tags: javascript, html, git, github

When i want to push github throw thi error

**github**

```
PS D:\projects\assignment-11> git commit -m"fake data removed"
[main d671435] fake data removed
 9 files changed, 80 insertions(+), 71 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 src/media/no-item.png
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ProgrammingHeroWC4/warehouse-management-client-side-ifty03.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: The error message is very clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says what you have to do. `git pull`, merge changes, then `git push`